# juju bootstrap not working for MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm following this doc to implement openstack using MAAS and JUJU:

[Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure with MAAS and Juju](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_MAAS_and_Juju)

So to setup JUJU, im following this one: [Get Started With Juju](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_MAAS_and_Juju)

Any idea about how to fix this one?

```
root@ubuntu:~/.juju# juju status -e maas -v
2013-07-28 17:31:47 ERROR juju supercommand.go:235 command failed: file 'provider-          state' not found not found
error: file 'provider-state' not found not found

root@ubuntu:~/.juju# juju bootstrap -e maas -v
2013-07-28 17:36:27 ERROR juju supercommand.go:235 command failed: cannot create     bootstrap state file: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 400 BAD REQUEST
error: cannot create bootstrap state file: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 400     BAD REQUEST
```

maas section of environments.yaml

```
  maas:
type: maas
# Change this to where your MAAS server lives.  It must specify the base path.
maas-server: 'http://192.168.119.140/MAAS'
maas-oauth: '********hidden****8:P6srrdD57RckEfJeEa2r'
admin-secret: fa4fb05****hidden*****e6f2d3fd29cb1f
default-series: precise
authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/authorized_keys # or any file you want.
```

And it seems this bug is fixed but I am still facing this issue with the latest version of JUJU:

[Bug Description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1204507)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MAAS on 12.04 they made some changes to juju-core. Below is the bug report for MAAS along with the fix.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1204507

Comment: Yeah, I see that the bug is fixed. Is this fix not available as a patch to install through apt-get or any idea when it will be available?   Also I see that the main documentation is meant for 12.04 - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure  Where can I find the similar documentation to deploy openstack using MAAS + JUJU on 13.04